# When I call onStart() to call another acitvity my app crashes

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app. In order to process user input I'm using `onStart()`  to check for input and then, I call another activity using a button.

```
protected void onStart()
{
    Button searchrestrauntbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchrestrauntbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText area = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.area);
            EditText locality = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locality);
            String area1 = area.getText().toString();
            String locality1 = locality.getText().toString();
            if(area1.equals(""))
            {
                area.setError("please enter an area");
            }
            else if(locality1.equals(""))
            {
                locality.setError("please provide locality");
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intentsearch = new Intent(HomePage.this,displayrestraunt.class);
                startActivity(intentsearch);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a call to super.onStart() method

check out the activity [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart())

Comment: oh yeah..sorry my bad..been banging my head for hours for nothing :P